# How do I turn Pagination Off?

Tags: sitefinity

I am using the MVC Widget Template to read a list of Dynamic Content, but need to be able to query the list.  Because it has pagination, it only goes through the first 20 or so.  How do I turn this off?

I Tried using this but didnt work:

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="KBList" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemsContainer" runat="server"
    EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="False"
    AllowPaging="False">

    My Code Here:


     @model Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.DynamicContent.Mvc.Models.DynamicContentListViewModel

        @using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.DynamicContent.WidgetTemplates.Fields.Helpers;
        @using Telerik.Sitefinity;
        @using Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ContentLinks;
        @using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Helpers;
        @using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Models;
        @using Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.DataResolving;
        @using Telerik.Sitefinity.Model.ContentLinks;
        @using Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Pages;

        @Html.Script(ScriptRef.JQuery, "top", false)



        <div class="@Model.CssClass">
            <ul>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                {
                    var navigateUrl = HyperLinkHelpers.GetDetailPageUrl(item, ViewBag.DetailsPageId, ViewBag.OpenInSamePage, Model.UrlKeyPrefix);
                    <li @Html.InlineEditingAttributes(Model.ProviderName, Model.ContentType.FullName, (Guid)item.Fields.Id)>


                        <h3>
                            <a @Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("Title", "ShortText") href="@navigateUrl">
                                @item.Fields.Title
                            </a>
                        </h3>

                    </li>
                }
            </ul>

            @if (Model.ShowPager)
            {
                @Html.Action("Index", "ContentPager", new { currentPage = Model.CurrentPage, 
                                totalPagesCount = Model.TotalPagesCount.Value, 
                                redirectUrlTemplate = ViewBag.RedirectPageUrlTemplate })
            }

        </div>
```

Comment: You have not defined `PageSize` property, try setting it say to 100.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me with HOW, to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the widget in page edit mode and there find the List Settings tab and once there you select the No Limit and Paging option.

This way, all items will be sent to the view.

Comment: Im using the MVC view, when I click on the "Edit" button nothing happens.

Comment: Is this a custom widget or a built in? When you click Edit, normally a widget designer should popup. Do you see any js errors in the console?

Comment: It is a MVC Widget Template (created when the Module type was created).

I see a WARNING when trying to open the edit section:
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap:
https://www.benchmarkseniorliving.com/kendo.all.min.js.map

Comment: so, just to confirm - you drag the built-in MVC widget to a page and when you click Edit of the widget - you dont see its designer popup at all?

Comment: Correct.  It tries to "load" but nothing happens.

Comment: Something is not right then, but hard to tell from here. I guess you already tried the obvious restart of the app pool?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your own MVC widget. In the Index method of your controller try fetching all content using resolveType of the dynamic module and (if needed convertinto required model) and pass it to your view file.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DynamicModuleManager dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager(String.Empty,"SomeName");
        Type dynArticleType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType(resolveType);
        var FilteredCollection = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(dynArticleType)
                        .Where(x => x.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && x.Status != ContentLifecycleStatus.Deleted
                        && x.Status != ContentLifecycleStatus.Temp && x.Status != ContentLifecycleStatus.Master)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.GetValue<System.DateTime>("PublicationDate"));
        var fullList = FilteredCollection.ToList();
       //Convert into customModel.
        return View("Default", yourCustomModel);
    }
```